# hi! how can I read data from sql database and to make into a list of objects (maching class in c#)

Tags: c#, sql, database, list, linq

```
con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=xxxxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=Person.costumer  ;integrated security=true");
// cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from agents", con);

string selectquery = "select * from agents";
SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(selectquery, con);
DataTable table = new DataTable();
adpt.Fill(table);
```

so now i have the data in a table , how can i convert it to a list of objects?

i want to know how can i take sql data and make it into a list of a class i declared that maches the sql table
i did it and it dosent let me to do :to list()

Comment: You don't need to load data into a DataTable to get objects from it. You can use an ORM like [EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli) to load objects directly

Comment: It sounds like now may be a good time to start looking into Entity Framework as your data access tool.

Comment: Or you can use [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) to execute a SQL query and map the results to objects directly, without having to specify any mappings in advance, eg: `var agents=connection.Query<Agent>("SELECT * From Agents");`

Comment: thank you:)  i see the data on the form in the DataGreedView is there a way to do it with out the dapper?

Comment: @נחמהלובלינג: Well, you could manually loop over the [rows of the `DataTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.rows) and populate your objects, adding a new object to a collection each time.  Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 0):

Getting into a DataTable in between is unnecessary. You can simply use Linq To SQL or Linq To EF. Here is a sample with Linq To SQL:

```
void Main()
{
  DataContext db = new DataContext(@"server=.;trusted_connection=yes;database=Northwind");
  Table<Customer> Customers = db.GetTable<Customer>();
  
  var lstCustomers = Customers.Where(c => c.Country == "USA").ToList();
  // It is an IQueryable, materialized into a List with ToList().
  // do something with the list

}

[Table(Name = "Customers")]
public class Customer
{
    [Column]
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string ContactTitle { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Region { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

If you had a DataTable initially, for whatever reason, then you could use Linq To DataSet to get a list. ie:

```
void Main()
{
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Customers where Country='USA'",
        @"server=.;trusted_connection=yes;database=Northwind")
        .Fill(tbl);
        
    
    var lstCustomers =
     tbl.AsEnumerable().ToList();

    var lst2 = tbl.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new MyCustomer {Id = (string)row["CustomerId"], Company=(string)row["CompanyName"] });
    
    // LinqPad
    //lstCustomers.Dump(); 
    //lst2.Dump();
}

public class MyCustomer
{ 
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
}
```